# new function question for better interpretation

Tags: java, arrays, return

looking to interpret this info better or additional resources.

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\test\\a.txt");
    BufferedReader fileInput = new BufferedReader(file);
      
    // Print first 3 lines of file "C:\test\a.txt"
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) 
        System.out.println(fileInput.readLine());
      
    fileInput.close();
```

Comment: Hi @doug22 - you've already returned the array - `return values`.  Depending what you want to print you do a for loop over the array and print out what you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: I'm not completely sure what the question is but if you say 'the address of the array is printed', are you using ```System.out.println(values)```? If so, you have to use ```System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values))``` instead.

Comment: I'm guessing that you probably need to [override method 'toString'](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/) in your classes, including `Address`, `Agency` and `Property`.

Comment: Have you read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: hi thanks, removed the extra code.  I do have a toString in my other classes, is there a way i can have two toStrings?

Answer (score 1):

What you interpreted as the address of the array was probably its hashcode, which is part of `Object`'s default implementation of `toString()`. An array is a type of object, and any objects that don't implement their own `toString()` will show up this way when printed.

To print the contents, you'll have to loop over them. One way to do that would be

```java
System.out.println(
    Arrays.stream(values).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
    );
```

One more remark: If you need a method to return several values, it's more idiomatic to return a `Collection` (or a subtype like `List`), because those are easier to work with in Java. That would also spare you having to loop over the data twice to determine the necessary size first.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Property[] getPropertiesBetween(int minUsd, int maxUsd) {
    int counter = 0;
    int a = 0;
    for (Property land : properties.values()) {
        if (land.getPriceUsd() > minUsd && land.getPriceUsd() < maxUsd) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    Property[] values = new Property[counter];
    for (Property land : properties.values()) {
        if (land.getPriceUsd() > minUsd && land.getPriceUsd() < maxUsd) {
            values[a] = land;
            a++;
        }
    }

   for(int i : values) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }


    return values; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Arrays;      
public class ReturnArray1
    {  
     public static void main(String args[])  
     {  
        int[] a=numbers();           //obtain the array  
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) //for loop to print the array  
           System.out.print( a[i]+ " ");     
     }  
     public static int[] numbers()  
     {  
        int[] arr={5,6,2,8,3,1,4,7,9,0};  //initializing array  
        return arr;  
     }  

    }
```

The method returns an array of integer types.